# How do I tell the Android launcher to create a folder with specified applications in it?

Tags: android

The question about says it all. I want to programmatically tell the default launcher/home screen to add a folder with a specific name and a specific set of apps in it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible, at least now. You can add only shortcuts. For reference see Launcher2 sources.